# How to combine Two Tables without common Column Fields?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

```
  ;WITH K_RT_MasterRetailStoresTable (CommonId,Branch) AS
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Branch) AS CommonId,Branch
FROM K_RT_MasterRetailStores
 )
 ,K_BR_AddBranchTable (CommonId, branch) AS
 (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY branch) AS CommonId,branch
FROM K_BR_AddBranch
 )
 ,K_HM_BranchTable (CommonID,branch) as
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY branch) as CommonId,branch
FROM K_HM_Branch
 )
,k_Master_BranchesTable (CommonID, branch) as
 (
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY BRANCH) AS COMMONID,BRANCH
FROM k_Master_Branches
 ) 
  SELECT MRS.BRANCH,AB.BRANCH,B.BRANCH,MB.BRANCH 
  FROM K_RT_MasterRetailStoresTable MR
  LEFT OUTER JOIN K_BR_AddBranchTable AB ON MR.COMMONID = AB.COMMONID 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN K_HM_BranchTable B ON AB.COMMONID = B.COMMONID 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN k_Master_BranchesTable MB ON B.COMMONID = MB.COMMONID
```

Here it display 4 Columns ,4 branches data..but i want to display single column all branches data..how can i do this?

Comment: why use `AND` in your outer joins since no `AND` condition is specified after that?

Comment: i removed AND ,now it's executed..it shows 4 column from 4 different tables..Now i want to shows only single column in all branches..how to write..please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 ;WITH K_RT_MasterRetailStoresTable (CommonId,Branch) AS
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Branch) AS CommonId,Branch
FROM K_RT_MasterRetailStores
)
 ,K_BR_AddBranchTable (CommonId, branch) AS
 (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY branch) AS CommonId,branch
FROM K_BR_AddBranch
)
 ,K_HM_BranchTable (CommonID,branch) as
(
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY branch) as CommonId,branch
FROM K_HM_Branch
)
,k_Master_BranchesTable (CommonID, branch) as
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY BRANCH) AS COMMONID,BRANCH
FROM k_Master_Branches
) 

SELECT distinct BRANCH FROM K_RT_MasterRetailStoresTable
UNION ALL
SELECT distinct BRANCH FROM K_BR_AddBranchTable
UNION ALL
SELECT distinct BRANCH FROM K_HM_BranchTable
UNION ALL
SELECT distinct BRANCH FROM k_Master_BranchesTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

Un wanted AND is there in below statements.

```
 LEFT OUTER JOIN K_BR_AddBranchTable AB ON MR.COMMONID = AB.COMMONID AND
 LEFT OUTER JOIN K_HM_BranchTable B ON AB.COMMONID = B.COMMONID AND
```

Comment: Here i am getting answer right now..It shows 4 Columns with Branch Title..But i want to display single Column ...Now what i Do?

Comment: Use SELECT B.BRANCH instead of SELECT MRS.BRANCH,AB.BRANCH,B.BRANCH,MB.BRANCH.

Comment: if i gave SELECT B.BRANCH shows only one table column